`do_bulk_insert` Requires Existing Collection - MilvusException: collection not found
I'm attempting to use do_bulk_insert to create a new collection but I'm encountering an error indicating that the collection does not exist. The error message states:
MilvusException: (code=100, message=collection not 
found[database=default][collection=a552b9ad4_adb1_47e0_9e98_33d913b52757])

Is it necessary to create an empty collection with a schema beforehand to use do_bulk_insert, or was it possible to create collections directly with this method in a previous version? I successfully used this feature a few weeks ago without this issue.

Yes you need a collection with that name first that has the matching schema that you want to load into.
